# Can't launch any Linux on hi-end hardware?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, hardware-failure

there a tough one: I've bought a new computer with the following configuration:

> ASUS Rampage III Extreme
>   Core i7 950
>   ZOTAC AMP! GeForce GTX 560
>   KINGSTON KHX1600C9D3K3 3x4GB
>   HAF 922
>   OCZ FATAL1TY 750W
>   SEAGATE 500GB ST3500413AS

After installation of **any** Linux I can't launch it! After grub screen, when it's supposed to launch system it gets stuck with black-screen(debian) or purple-sceen(ubuntu).

I installed various versions of **Ubuntu**, **Debian** with and without X, **Fedora**. Every time it's the same: total freeze after grub.

Can anyone help me, please? I **don't want** to stuck with **Windows** (which is running perfectly as never)!

Answer (score 1):

Install [NVIDIA Linux display drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-275.09.07-driver.html)!

> Release Date:
>   2011.07.13
>
> Added support for the following GPUs:
>
> - GeForce GTX 560
> - GeForce GT 545
>     ...

Comment: Please! I've already mentioned that i tried Debian without x-server.

Comment: Unrelated. X or not X - add anyway, maybe - using second more light V/Card

Comment: How can i install drivers, when i even cant launch the system!? It freezes right after grub-screen!

Comment: Show Grub config, obviously

Comment: How? It's all defaults. Freshly installed systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to a console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. If you can see the login prompt then this is a display driver issue. A common problem with Linux for new hardware.

If display driver is the issue go to the ASUS website and download the linux driver if they have it for your motherboard.

Comment: It wont even go that far. I mentioned before that I tried Debian without x-server. Also, ASUS Rampage III Extreme has no onboard graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still an issue, try booting with a live CD (Ubuntu should work just fine), and check the latest logs in `/var/log` to see what happened during the last boot. It could be that some default setting or kernel version is not working for the given hardware.

Comment: I gave up long time ago. I'm running Debian as virtual machine. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: @seler: Sorry to hear that. I've had problems with new hardware on Linux before, but usually some googling or a *detailed* SO question turns up a solution.

Comment: It's just there are no linux drivers for my build.